# How to add gridColumnStart and gridRowStart in javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I would like to change the color of a particular grid field.I don't know how to add gridColumnStart and gridRowStart to my line of code.

```
 document.getElementsByClassName('grid').style.backgroundColor ="#FE2E64";
```

Comment: possible duplicate of : https://stackoverflow.com/q/10693845/8620333

Answer (score 1):

```
 document.getElementsByClassName('grid')
```

returns a HTML collection - which essentially is an array. It doesn't have a **style** property. Instead you must loop over the elements inside the array and change the style of those.

```
var myGrid = document.getElementsByClassName('grid');
for(var a=0;a<myGrid.length;a++)
{
  myGrid[a].style.backgroundColor ="#FE2E64";
}
```

If **grid** is the ID of an acutal html element, you can't use **getElementsByClassName()** at all.
In this case use

```
document.getElementById("grid")
```